# Scratch card effect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

i need to do a scratch effect to reveal the layer beneath, that would be for me to play with the alpha channel of an image. What would be the best way to go forward?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There's a question about this here: [Create masking effect over a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007750)

Comment: it crashes when you add the scratch layer multiple times

Comment: i think it may be alloc problem

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, the best way to do this is to use openGL. Just lay the image in a UIImageView, then place an opaque openGL layer on top. Then draw using GL_LINE_STRIP, and a glBlenFunc(GL_ZERO, GL_ZERO) on user touch.

Comment: Thanks. I got enough response to get going :) .

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `modalTransitionStyle` property of a `UIViewController` to `UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl` or `UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve` and then display it using

```
[[self navigationController] presentModalViewController:someVC animated:YES]`
```

Not sure whether this would give you the desired effect though.

([This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401543/how-to-create-a-page-curl-animation) is how the PartialCurl looks like.)

Comment: Even better would be to use _UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve_ which is like a fade effect.

Comment: thanks for the advice but it will have to depend on the touch area. Not sure I have this kind of conrol using the uimodaltransition.