# How to create a page curl animation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, uiview

Any way to emulate something like this?  Isn't there an API for doing something like a "Half page curl" or something?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

UIModalTransitionStyle
Transition styles available when presenting view controllers modally. The below are the four different transition styles. The *"UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl"* is the one you're after.

```
typedef enum {
    UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical,
    UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal,
    UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve,
    UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl,
} UIModalTransitionStyle;
```

Apple documentations: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. In this case Settings is a sublcass UIViewController to be presented behind the page curl. self is also a UIViewController that is being displayed an it's view will stay on top.

```
-(void)presentSettings{
    Settings *eset = [[Settings alloc] init];
    //eset.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
    eset.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
    [self presentModalViewController:eset animated:YES];
}
```

Notice that the Curl is only available in iOS 3.2 and later.

Comment: What does `modalPresentationStyle` do?

Comment: UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl needs a fullscreen display to work and UIModalPresentationFullScreen makes sure the modal presentation is fullscreen. I believe  UIModalPresentationFullScreen that is the default, thus you can ignore that line.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be what you're looking for:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: I was actually looking for a HALF page curl where the top view doesn't disappear but instead stays visible.